# cp: cannot stat '/some/path/*': No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash-scripting

My script code is:

```
var="/some/path"
cp "$var*" "/another/path"
```

Then it throws:

```
cp: cannot stat '/some/path/*': No such file or directory
```

I have tried this and got the same error:

```
cp "${var}*" "/another/path"
```

Finally, I solved this problem by:

```
cp "$var"* "/another/path"
```

This time the command executes successfully, but I'd like to know WHY.

Could you please give out an explanation ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use `"$var*"` the output will be `/some/path*`, where `*` is considered as a character (not as a wildcard, since it's inside the double quotes - [see globs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))).
So in your case (`/some/path/*`), `cp` is searching for a file/folder named `*` inside the `path` directory.

When it's outside the double quotes it's considered as a wildcard, meaning anything that starts with `path` (`path1`, `path2` etc). 
Or if `path/*` (anything that is on that directory).

Comment: globs are globs, not regular expressions

Comment: @CervEd thanks for your message! Changed it to wildcard (was not familiar if it was a wildcard or regex at the time of writing).